# count of distinct patients per doctor per month for a rolling period of 12 month(11 months look back from the current month)

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table with doctor_id,claim_date(date type),claim_date_mo_id(char type) and patient_id.
Sample dataset for one doctor is shown below:

```
**DOCTOR_ID**   **CLAIM_DATE**  **CLAIM_DATE_MO_ID**    **PATIENT_ID**  
22222         7/29/2015       201507        12769998  
22222         9/29/2015       201509        12769998  
22222         9/7/2016        201609        756850  
22222         10/6/2016       201610        756850  
22222         4/11/2017       201704        837125  
22222         4/11/2017       201704        837125  
22222         4/11/2017       201704        837125  
22222         4/13/2017       201704        892834  
22222         5/15/2017       201705        837125  
22222         5/15/2017       201705        837125  
22222         5/15/2017       201705        837125  
22222         7/6/2017        201707        892834  
22222         9/6/2017        201709        17539987  
22222         9/19/2017       201709        837125  
22222         10/3/2017       201710        756850  
22222         10/3/2017       201710        756850  
22222         10/9/2017       201710        17539987
```

The output should be as follows:

```
**DOCTOR_ID**   **CLAIM_DATE_MO_ID**    **count(distinct patient)**  
22222             201507              1  
22222             201509              1  
22222             201609              1  
22222             201610              1  
22222             201704              3  
22222             201705              3  
22222             201707              3  
22222             201709              4  
22222             201710              4
```

The count is the number of distinct patients seen by the doctor from the current month to the last 11 months period.
For example 201507 denotes the period(201507-201408).

Note:I have to take the max of distinct patient count for any period.
One scenario is for the month_id 201704 where the count of distinct patients for last 11 month (excluding current month of 201704) is 2 till 11th April but for 13th April the count of distinct patients changes to 3 which is to be captured.
So for 201704 the count should be 3.

I tried the below query but I am not getting the desired output.

```
sel doctor_id,case when to_number(claim_date_mo_id)-lookback_12m is not null then claim_date_mo_id||lookback_12m end,count(distinct patient_id)  
from  
(  
sel doctor_id,patient_id,claim_date_mo_id ,
to_number(to_char(cast(trim(claim_date_mo_id)||'01' as date format'YYYYMMDD') - interval '11' month 'YYYYMM')) as lookback_12m  
from table  
where doctor_id=22222  
) A  
group by 1,2
```

Comment: I would ignore claim_date_mo_id and consider using TRUNC(claim_date, ‘yyyymm’). Then look at using a COUNT(DISTINCT ) window aggregate that defines a window using ROWS BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(claim_date, -11) and CURRENT ROW and partitioned on the doctor_id. I think there are some other challenges because you are driving the group by the claim date in your fact table and there may be gaps where a doctor doesn’t have a claim. Regardless, I hope this helps point you in a direction toward a solution.

Comment: @RobPaller Thank you for the suggestion . But count(distinct) doesn't work with over() .

Comment: Good point that I had forgotten. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Teradata, so I'll answer as if it was the one I'm most proficient with (Firebird). What about

```
    select a.doctor_id,
           cast( cast( substring( a.claim_date_mo_id from 1 for 4 ) as integer ) - 1 as char( 4 ) ) || substring( a.claim_date_mo_id from 5 for 2 ) || '-' || a.claim_date_mo_id claim_period,
           count( distinct b.patient_id ) distinct_patients
    from table a
    join table b on a.doctor_id = b.doctor_id 
           and b.claim_date_mo_id > cast( cast( substring( a.claim_date_mo_id from 1 for 4 ) as integer ) - 1 as char( 4 ) ) || substring( a.claim_date_mo_id from 5 for 2 )
           and b.claim_date_mo_id <= a.claim_date_mo_id
    where a.doctor_id = 22222
    group by 1,2
```

Here's an alternative:

```
    WITH MyCTE( DOCTOR_ID, CLAIM_DATE_MO_ID, LOOKBACK_12M ) AS
    ( SELECT DISTINCT DOCTOR_ID, CLAIM_DATE_MO_ID, 
                      to_number(to_char(cast(trim(claim_date_mo_id)||'01' as date format'YYYYMMDD') - interval '11' month 'YYYYMM')) 
      FROM MyTable 
      WHERE DOCTOR_ID = 22222 )
    SELECT CTE.DOCTOR_ID, CTE.CLAIM_DATE_MO_ID || CTE.LOOKBACK_12M, COUNT(DISTINCT T.PATIENT_ID
    FROM MyCTE CTE
    JOIN MyTable T ON CTE.DOCTOR_ID = T.DOCTOR_ID
                  AND T.CLAIM_DATE_MO_ID >= CTE.LOOKBACK_12M
                  AND T.CLAIM_DATE_MO_ID <= CTE.CLAIM_DATE_MO_ID 
    GROUP BY 1, 2
```

HTH,
Set

Comment: Thank you for the query but this doesn't fetch the desired result.

Comment: Sorry to hear that it produced incorrect result, in what way was it incorrect? Anyway, I've edited my answer and given an alternative suggestion.

Comment: I tried converting it to Teradata equivalent:  

`SELECT CTE.DOCTOR_ID, CTE.CLAIM_DATE_MO_ID || CTE.LOOKBACK_12M, COUNT(DISTINCT T.PATIENT_ID)    FROM  (
SELECT DISTINCT DOCTOR_ID, CLAIM_DATE_MO_ID, 
 TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(CAST(TRIM(CLAIM_DATE_MO_ID) || '01' AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD') - INTERVAL '11' MONTH, 'YYYYMM') )   LOOKBACK_12M
 FROM MyTable
 WHERE DOCTOR_ID = 22222
)  CTE
JOIN MyTable T 
ON CTE.DOCTOR_ID = T.DOCTOR_ID
 AND CTE.CLAIM_DATE_MO_ID <= T.CLAIM_DATE_MO_ID 
                  AND CTE.LOOKBACK_12M     >= T.CLAIM_DATE_MO_ID
    GROUP BY 1, 2`  


But it returns 0 rows

Comment: I slightly changed the conditions and now it works perfectly fine.
AND CTE.CLAIM_DATE_MO_ID >= T.CLAIM_DATE_MO_ID 
                  AND CTE.LOOKBACK_12M     <= T.CLAIM_DATE_MO_ID
Can you please edit your answer so that I can mark it correct. Thanks a ton for your help :)

Comment: Of course lookback_12m should be before the date you're checking. Glad you worked out my silly mistake! I've corrected my answer